# What does the second derivative of a quadratic function actually mean?

Tags: derivatives, curvature

The second derivative of $y=ax^2 +bx +x$ is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2a$

But what does $2a$ mean in terms of the graph of this function?

Take the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$

It has a $2a$ value of $1$.

I understand that the second derivative expresses the concavity of a graph, but I can't see how a concavity of $1$ makes sense for this graph.

There have been posts similar to this topic but I have not seen a satisfactory answer.

Can anyone explain what it means to say that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ has a concavity of $1$ everywhere along the graph?

Comment: You can't really see anything specific on the graph, in general, except for qualitative properties (like concavity). It just means that the increase rate in the slope of the graph (i.e., the derivative of the derivative) has constant value $1$. And I never heard anybody say "a concavity of $1$", so I think this is not standard

Comment: It means that the slope differs by 1 at any two points $x$ and $x+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it means that the slope is increasing at a constant rate of 1 for positive $x$, similarly, it's decreasing at a constant rate of 1 for negative $x$.

Equivalently, the graph increases at an increasing rate (for positive $x$).

Compare this with the line $y=x$ which has $y''=0$. This means that the slope doesn't increase, which is what you see. The slope is constant.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

- if $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2a>0 \implies$ $f(x)$ is concave up (that is convex)
- if $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2a<0 \implies$ $f(x)$ is concave down (that is concave)

Comment: Possibly of interest:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636906/how-can-i-prove-that-exist-exactly-two-points-so-that-fx-0/2636980

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks Peter for the further reference!